# What is the velocity assigned to the gazebo-ros-conrtol controller

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I create a transmission for the wheels of my robot like this

```
  <transmission name="tran_robot_wheel">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wheel_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="wheel_motor">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
```

or

```
  <transmission name="tran_robot_wheel">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wheel_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="wheel_motor">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
```

And I configure the controller as so

```
  joint_wheel_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: wheel_joint
    pid: {p: 100, i: 10, d: 0.1}
```

or

```
  joint_wheel_controller:
    type: velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: wheel_joint
    pid: {p: 100, i: 10, d: 0.1}
```

And I run the simulation and sent a command to both left and right wheel to set velocity to 1.0

```
rostopic pub /robot/joint_wheel_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: 1.0"
```

The robot moves about 1 meter in 10 second. The robot wheel turns once around in about 8 seconds. What kind of velocity unit is that? How do I convert it to m/s?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21825/what-is-the-velocity-assigned-to-the-gazebo-ros-conrtol-controller/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The robot wheel turns around once in about 8 seconds (6.283, actually), because the value assigned as velocity is angular velocity `omega`

`omega = 2 * pi * f`

that means the time `t` it takes to turn the wheel all the way around

`t = 1/f`

is

`t = ( 2 * pi ) / omega = 2 * 3.1415 / 1 = 6.283 s`

and you need to assign the velocity `omega` of 6.283 to achieve 1 rotation per second

`omega = 2 * pi * f = 2 * 3.1415 * 1 = 6.283`

To get the desired linear velocity `v` you divide the desired linear velocity `v` with the radius `r` of the wheel in meters.

`v = 2 * pi * f * r = omega * r`

`omega = v / r`

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vaichu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24804/vaichu/) on 2020-03-20**:
I noticed that, right after controllers are spawned. They start to receive some noise as commands. is this normal?

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2020-03-30**:
Why do you think they receive noise as commands? Do you see that on the command topic?